# How can I use fallback js with angular modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdn, fallback

I'm using [fallback](http://www.fallback.io) to load a local file if the cdn is unavailable;

The readme states:
"The key must be the libraries window variable" - for example jQuery (or $ I guess) for jquery.

```
fallback.load({
    // [...]
    jQuery: [
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.FAIL_ON_PURPOSE.min.js',
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js',
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'
    ],

    'jQuery.ui': [
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js',
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js',
        '//js/loader.js?i=vendor/jquery-ui.min.js'
    ]
}, //[...] shim, callback etc 
});
```

However, when loading angularjs modules or jquery plugin, I do not have a window library to use as a test.

Is there any way to use the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:
- just use an expression that would return undefined if the library is not loaded:

This is the [github issue](https://github.com/dolox/fallback/issues/26) and this is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1mPmY?p=info):

```
fallback.load({
    //[...]
    'angular.module("ngRoute")': [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-route.min.js'
        ],
    //[...]
});
```